# How to make the call directly programmatically

Tags: android

I have tried this code here but it merely calls the in built app instead of making a call directly:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
 Uri.parse("tel:+" + phoneNumber));
 startActivity(i);
```

Any clue?

Comment: I don't think you can actually make a call without the native call app...

Comment: @DaanOlislagers hmm...is it? And why is that?

Comment: Well, probably because Android requires user interaction before making a call. So they redirect all call making applications to the native call app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this simply. It make the call directly.

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number")); 
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

and add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: App is throwning exception upon shaking. Logcat: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=03002261944 }

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman Check it you have pass the number in the same format which I have written in the answer

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman: Notably, `03002261944` is not a valid `Uri`.